# Does redeploying existing running pipeline re-process Ready time slices again?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Lets say you have an ADF pipeline which is provisioned and running fine, it has a certain start date and is not supposed to have end date (so the end date is like 9999 ..). It's running fine and processing hourly slices smoothly. Now if you make some change in the pipeline's property or simply hit space somewhere in Author & Deploy and simply redeploy, without any logical change as such, does the pipeline re-process all the time slices it has already processed earlier?

Comment: From my experience using ADF it should not be doing that.  Are you seeing that behavior?

Comment: No, I have not really tried that. But I just wanted to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen this behaviour while I've been working with it as if you push the start date back it will only process "new" slices i.e. not previously included in the range.

I have had a pipeline provisioning stall and fail when I've messed about with dates too much but I don't recall the steps.

Comment: So, what if you want existing pipeline to reprocess all the slices? What if we clone a pipeline and deploy, I guess that is the only option that will force reprocessing all the slices since technically it's a new pipeline altogether right?

Comment: IIRC that is what you are facing yes.

Comment: If you want to reprocess all slices then prepare a Powershell script that issues a `Set-AzureRmDataFactorySliceStatus` for each of the datasets in your pipeline. Set the status to `Waiting` and the UpdateType to `UpstreamInPipeline` and the Start and End date time range to cover the days you would like to re-run. You will of course need to manually clean-up any previously processed data if what you are re-running is not an idempotent operation.